# Unable to connect to Tor network using TLS

Tags: censorship, web-proxy, tls

I'm behind a corporate proxy, Tor always worked fine (using bridges) until few days ago, it seems that now the proxy only accepts TLS connections (no SSLv2/v3); Is there a way to solve this issue?
I can only connect to addresses on ports 80-443

```
[WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 1; recommendation warn)
[WARN] 7 connections have failed:
[WARN] 6 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object)
[WARN] 1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE
```